# How can I filter text out of a string containing numbers and text in PHP

Tags: php, filter-var

I want to filter out the text out of a string which contain numbers and letters.
Take for example,

```
 input       expected result(output)
R543.32 --->    R
gbp6.99 --->    gbp
```

How would I do that? I used `filter_var()` to get the numbers on their own, but cannot seem to find how to get the text on its own, at least not in a way that is scalable.

```
$buying_price_filtered = filter_var($buying_price, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, 
 FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

Comment: I never used `filter_var()` for that, maybe rexeg will work better you can easly search for patterns. https://regex101.com/ is a nice site to test your regex

Comment: Thank you @Baracuda078, I have heard of regex, will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `preg_replace` to remove the integers and special characters from the strings that you have.

Here i'll add a-z and A-Z together since there might be both capital and simple letters. So that you will get all the letters that are there in the word.

```
$str = 'R543.32';
$newstr =  preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $str);
echo $newstr;
//will return you the letters for the above ex: R will be the return
```

For further reference you can go [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace)